# Assistance with CakePHP model relationships

Tags: orm, cakephp

How would I represent the following in a CakePHP model?

```
Product
=======
product_id
....

Cart
====
cart_id
....

Carts_Products
==============
cart_id
product_id
quantity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing data in your join table (for a HABTM relation), you're situation looks quite similar to Rail's 'through' relation (seen at the bottom of [this diagram](http://mboffin.com/stuff/ruby-on-rails-data-relationships.png)). As such, you will want to create a model for that table and use Cake's 'with' relation setting seen on the [HABTM page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) of the book. You should then be able to access the data stored on the join table. By convention...

- your tables should be named `products`, `carts`, `carts_products`
- your models should be named `Product`, `Cart`, `CartsProduct`

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that (for CakePHP2) the column names for product and cart need to change.

```
products
========
id
name
...

carts
=====
id
create_date
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer to your question will be revealed on careful reading of [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) documentation page.

Comment: "RTFM" isn't a very helpful response.  Next time, try (gently) explaining that it's pretty well covered in such-and-such section of the docs, and (if possible) provide a link.  See deizel's response for a great example.

Comment: Thanks. I did find a relevant documentation page and use neutral language, but perhaps my response was interpreted as aggressive due to its terseness?

Comment: It was the implication that he hadn't already tried reading that page 'carefully' that came off sounding harsh.

I believe that if you have the time to post the link, you could also post a copy pasted example from the page.

This lets them see the code here, as well as gives them a visual clue in the code snippet as to what part of the page they should be more careful reading.